# Where condition in ZF2 using Anonymous function

Tags: php, zend-db, zend-framework2

As the official documentation say I'm using an anonymous PHP function in my ZF2 model ([Zend\Db\TableGateway](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html))

```
 use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
 use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
 $artistTable = new TableGateway('artist', $adapter);

 // search for at most 2 artists who's name starts with Brit, ascending
 $rowset = $artistTable->select(function (Select $select) {
      $select->order('name ASC');
 });
```

How to pass an argument in this anonymous function to add a filter in the where condition?

I would like to use something like that:

```
$this->select(function (Select $select) {
            $select->where(array('artist', $artist));
            $select->order('name ASC');
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$artist = 'John';
$rowset = $artistTable->select(function (Select $select) use ($artist) {
    $select->where(array('artist', $artist));
    $select->order('name ASC');
});
```